# Docker vs wsl2 resource utilization

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

So I have this question, should I install docker on windows 10 then have an ubuntu 20.04 image running there,, or install wsl2 on windows 10 then have ubuntu 20.04 installed and running, which method is low in RAM

Comment: Docker and WSL2 are 2 very different things. For your use case, which I think is being able to run Linux commands on Windows, you might want to use WSL2. Docker can be used as well but sharing the files between host and container, port mapping b/w them etc. will be a big pain.

Comment: So are you saying docker runs on linux better then windows??

Comment: No, I am saying that‍♂️. what I am saying is wsl2 will provide you with an better command line interface and overall experience of Linux system. docker isn't just for running linux, it's for running applications in a containerized way. While WSL2 was specifically built to allow users to run Linux kernel on windows.

Comment:  sorry for making you put a hand on the face emoji,, i might be an ignorent fool for sure but i was just having a diffrent idea,, and you made it clear now thanks

Comment: @AnubhavUjjawal could you elaborate on "running applications in a containerized way" vs "run linux kernel on windows"? Does this mean that you can't run Linux apps in a Docker container on Windows? Or are you saying that you can run Linux apps in Docker on Windows, but things like filesystem and networking takes more work? Either way, why?

Comment: So running applications in a containerized way means package up an application with all of the parts it needs, such as libraries and other dependencies, and deploy/run it as one package. So running ubuntu on docker means just running the ubuntu base image as a container. You can run anything you want inside that container. However, filesystem b/w host and docker container aren't shared, you have to share them explicitly. You will have to mount a volume on docker and keep all your working files inside that volume or copy files in and out of container whenever you want to do something with it.

Comment: Also, docker containers, are run on a different network from the host container. So, by default, either you have to map ports b/w host and container and then access the services running inside those containers using the host's port mapping, or run it using a --network host option (Which is better, I think). Also, every time you run a container using docker, it consumes some disk space. 

However, if you install WSL2, you won't have to think of all these things. You can get started just right away.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question more directly: Docker usually consumes less RAM as it's designed to run containerized applications in a minimalistic environment. WSL2 on the other hand has an issue freeing up resources. There are some mitigations you can do such as limiting the amount of RAM WSL2 is allowed to use. However standard Linux behavior is to use all the RAM and not leave anything behind. In fact, this is a big part of what makes WSL2 so much faster than WSL1 and in some cases, even faster than Windows itself. However as mentioned in the comments above, Docker isn't intended to be a dev environment but a test environment. You could run docker directly in WSL2 or use Docker for Windows with WSL2 backend. WSL2 should be used for your CLI. I should also mention since you specifically stated Ubuntu, that Multipass and Hyper-V are other options you could go with but the experience will be a bit different than WSL. It simply depends on your use-case.